# Globbing not working with gulp eslint with jsx files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp, eslint

Here is my `lint` task:

```
gulp.task('lint', function(){
  gulp.src(fileString)
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format());
});
```

If `fileString` is `'js/**/*.js'`, it lints just the .js files perfectly fine. If it's `'js/components/**.jsx'`, it lints the .jsx perfectly fine. But `'js/**/*.jsx'` or `'js/**/*/.*{js,jsx}'`, it see's all the correct files, but does nothing with them.

Here's my `/js` directory (for a react project):

```
├── stores
│   └── heyStore.jsx
├── models.js
├── mixins.js
├── data
│   └── states.js
├── config.js
├── components
│   ├── firstThing.jsx
│   ├── aThing.jsx
│   ├── whoaWhat.jsx
│   └── nahYo.jsx
├── app.jsx
└── api
    ├── prod.js
    └── mock.js
```

And just in case, here's my `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true,
    "arrowFunctions": true,
    "blockBindings": true,
    "generators": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "strict": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "curly": 0,
    "no-multi-spaces": 0,
    "key-spacing": 0,
    "no-return-assign": 0,
    "consistent-return": 0,
    "no-shadow": 0,
    "no-comma-dangle": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": 0,
    "no-empty": 0,
    "new-parens": 0,
    "no-cond-assign": 0,
    "quotes": [2, "single", "avoid-escape"],
    "camelcase": 0,
    "semi": [2, "always"],
    "new-cap": [1, { "capIsNew": false }],
    "no-undef": 2
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "globals": {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix [here](https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint/issues/12#issuecomment-51423177).

Basically my gulp task looks like:

```
gulp.task('lint', function(){
  gulp.src('js/**/*.{js,jsx}')
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .on('data', function(file) {
      if(file.eslint.messages && file.eslint.messages.length){
        gulp.fail = true;
      }
    });

});

process.on('exit', function() {
  if (gulp.fail) {
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

I'm not sure why this was needed or why that fixed it, though.

Answer (score 0):

As input to gulp.src you could provide an array of [globs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob). Actually this combination should work: [`js/**/*.js`, `js/**/*.jsx`]. If you say only `js/components/**.jsx`, also it's far from ideal, use what works for you: [`js/**/*.js`, `js/components/**.jsx`, `js/**.jsx`, `js/stores/**.jsx`]